Reset Angular template reference variable
In my Angular application I use this code with the template reference variable swiper
div *ngIf="stateName == 'SCHEDULE'">
  <swiper-container #swiper [pagination]="true">
  ...

If stateName changes from SCHEDULE to another string and than back do SCHEDULE than the @ViewChild variable is undefined in component (@ViewChild('swiper') public swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined;)
My question now would be how can I reset te swiperRef variable?

What do you mean by "reset"? Won't it become undefined once the element is removed from the DOM?

Remember that you need "wait" to repaint, see, e.g. this SO

Try use ChangeDetectionRef.detectChanges after stateName changes.
